# Using web2py on Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, web2py

I am trying to use the steps I found on the net to make web2py work on Eclipse, but I must have something setup wrong because Eclipse gives me error on the imports.

For instance the instructions say to do this at the top of controllers:

```
    if 0:
        from gluon.globals import *
        from gluon.html import *
        from gluon.http import *
        from gluon.tools import *
        from gluon.sql import *
        from gluon.validators import *
        from gluon.languages import translator as T
        from gluon.sqlhtml import SQLFORM, SQLTABLE, form_factory
        session = Session()
        request = Request()
        response = Response()
        crud = Crud()
        db = DAL(‘sqlite://storage.sqlite’)
        auth=Auth(globals(),None)
```

Eclipse says T is an unresolved import. If I change it to translator (instead of translator as T) it says translator is in unresolved import.

Also it says SQLFORM, SQLTable, form_factory, Session(), Request(), Response etc, are unresolved imports? Any ideas what I am doing wrong before I switch to Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these [steps first](http://www.web2py.com/AlterEgo/default/show/37).

Then do what I have above.  Urghhh